# Bootable USB created on Mac to format PC

Tags: windows, usb, startup

I'm trying to create a bootable USB in my mac to fix a windows PC. However I've tried everything and didn't find exacly the way. I've tried with boot camp but don't even appear the option to create a USB drive. I've tried with terminal (sudo dd if=/location/of/iso of=/dev/diskN) and after all the waiting i've only return with a message from my windows PC "create a bootable drive and insert it again".

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work as you noticed.

I'd recommend using unetbootin from https://unetbootin.github.io/. Just follow the instructions there or use the instructions from the ubuntu page (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos)

If you want to use the command line, do e.g. (MAKE SURE TO REPLACE WITH THE CORRECT PARTITIONS!)

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o destination_file.img source_file.iso
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk2 1 "Free Space" "unused" "100%"
dd if=destination_file.img.dmg of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
diskutil eject /dev/disk2
```

Comment: Can you explain me the code for terminal?

Comment: You want to convert the CD/DVD "iso" image to a (dmg) partition image, partition your USB stick to one partition, copy the partition image to the partition on the usb stick and eject the usb stick - line by line.